# Load .asc file into azure machine learning

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

For my Azure Machine Learning experiment I want to load a .asc file into an Execute R script in my experiment. It is in fact a tab delimited file with some comments on the first couple of rows. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

A csv goes well, but with this file I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload this file as part of the zip file. Follow the steps provided under heading "Script Bundle" - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-r-quickstart/

Comment: But in the end I want to use this file as input for a web service. Don't think this is a solution,  is it?

Comment: If that is the case, then provide a sample tab separated values as part of the "enter data" module

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new data set and upload the csv file after selecting the right data type "**GenericTSVNoHeader**" or with header.

On you experiment, you will be able to view or visualize the data set and then do any manipulation you can add execute R script module.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you plan to send each line of the text file as parameter to the webservice, then you can also use the "enter data" module for providing the data as shown below

[image]

If you want to send the whole file as a parameter to the web service, then I would recommend to use reader with SQL or blob option, clean first couple of rows first, and then use SQL script or blob credentials as web service parameter as described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-web-service-parameters/)